# where does ISD init keys come from while card in OP_READY status?

Tags: globalplatform

I am recently doing some study on Global Platfrom Card. I got a questions while reading the specs. 
 The spec 2.2.1 mentioned while In OP_READY status, it's able to load, install Supplementary Security Domains. and this is the very beginning state of Card.
 However, it also mentioned for install Supplementary Security Domains, "An initial key shall be available within the Issuer Security Domain.". which make me confused. 
Where are there initial key from? 
Is it pre implanted in the factory?

I found some docs said, the initial keys for ISD is diversified from "Key diversification data" which is returned by doing "INITIALIZE UPDATE" request. Is this true? How can I generate initial keys from this data?

Big thanks for your answers!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys get implanted implicitly during personalization phase. I suggest to also read Common Criteria protection profiles and/or javacard security targets to get a better understanding of the GP spec and overall lifecycle.

Comment: thank you for your answer and advicem,I think i did not make it clear. you mentioned the keys implanted during personalization phase, however what I want to know is the keys used before doing personalization. In my situation, SE is initially in OP_READY status, which supposed to be the first state after factory. While I was analyzing the process of installing the first  Supplementary Security Domain, I found it used secure channel doing this job. I am wonderring which keys initialize the " very beginning secure channel", and where it come from? Can it be calculated?

Comment: If the keys use some kind of diversification, the key derivation scheme MAY use information from the response of INITIALIZE UPDATE. You just need to know the actual keys and any diversification mechanism, it could be whatever proprietary method for example.